# How to render more elements of list on button click - Meteor / React

Tags: list, reactjs, render

I have a problem with rendering more items of list on button click. At the moment I render 3 items and on click I want to render another 3 items in place on previous ones.

Let say user see three first items of the list (Medicines / Meals / Activities) and user wants to check another 3 when click on right-arrow button (currently commented Sleep / Cigarettes / Alcohol). I want to give possibility to render previous 3 on button with left arrow class and next 3 on button with right arrow class. I tried various stuff without resoult.

```
render () {
const medicinesTaken = this.getMedicinesTaken()
const mealsConsumed = this.getMealsConsumed()
const activitiesMinutes = this.getActivitiesMinutes()
const hoursSlept = this.getHoursSlept()
const cigarettesSmoked = this.getCigarettesSmoked()
const alcoholDrunk = this.getAlcoholDrunk()
return (
  <div>
    <button className='arrow-left' />
    <ul className='list-icons list-inline'>
      <li className='calendar-icon'>
        <Medicines medicinesTaken={medicinesTaken} increment={this.incrementMedicines}
          decrement={this.decrementMedicines} />
      </li>
      <li className='calendar-icon'>
        <Meals mealsConsumed={mealsConsumed} increment={this.incrementMeals} decrement={this.decrementMeals} />
      </li>
      <li className='calendar-icon'>
        <Activities activitiesMinutes={activitiesMinutes} increment={this.incrementActivities}
          decrement={this.decrementActivities} />
      </li>
      {/*<li className='calendar-icon'>*/}
        {/*<Sleep hoursSlept={hoursSlept} increment={this.incrementSleep}*/}
          {/*decrement={this.decrementSleep} />*/}
      {/*</li>*/}
      {/*<li className='calendar-icon'>*/}
        {/*<Cigarettes cigarettesSmoked={cigarettesSmoked} increment={this.incrementCigarettes}*/}
          {/*decrement={this.decrementCigarettes} />*/}
      {/*</li>*/}
      {/*<li className='calendar-icon'>*/}
        {/*<Alcohol alcoholDrunk={alcoholDrunk} increment={this.incrementAlcohol}*/}
          {/*decrement={this.decrementAlcohol} />*/}
      {/*</li>*/}
    </ul>
    <button className='arrow-right' />
  </div>
)
```

}
How can I achieve it?

[image]

Comment: I could possibly set initial state to let say firstThreeItems: true, secondThreeItems: false and change these values on button click and than check state and render it accordingly to state but I think there must be better solution

Answer (score 1):

I'd add the elements to an array and then use the index to show the next items.

```
state = {
   array: [
     <Medicines medicinesTaken={medicinesTaken} increment={this.incrementMedicines}
          decrement={this.decrementMedicines} />,
     <Meals mealsConsumed={mealsConsumed} increment={this.incrementMeals} decrement={this.decrementMeals} />,
     <Activities activitiesMinutes={activitiesMinutes} increment={this.incrementActivities}
          decrement={this.decrementActivities} />,
     <Sleep hoursSlept={hoursSlept} increment={this.incrementSleep}
          decrement={this.decrementSleep} />,
     <Cigarettes cigarettesSmoked={cigarettesSmoked} increment={this.incrementCigarettes} decrement={this.decrementCigarettes} />,
     <Alcohol alcoholDrunk={alcoholDrunk} increment={this.incrementAlcohol} decrement={this.decrementAlcohol} />
   ],

   startFrom: 0
}

render() {

  const items = []
  for(let i = this.state.startFrom; i < this.state.array.length; i++) {
    items.push(<li>this.state.array[i]<li>);
  }
  return (
    <div>
      <button className='arrow-left' onClick={() => this.setState({startFrom: this.state.startFrom - 3)}/>
      <ul className='list-icons list-inline'>
        {items}
      </ul>
      <button className='arrow-right' onClick={() => this.setState({startFrom: this.state.startFrom + 3)}/>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Or you can also do it with simple booleans. Like:

```
state = {
  firstThree: true
}

render () {
const {firstThree} = this.state;
const medicinesTaken = this.getMedicinesTaken()
const mealsConsumed = this.getMealsConsumed()
const activitiesMinutes = this.getActivitiesMinutes()
const hoursSlept = this.getHoursSlept()
const cigarettesSmoked = this.getCigarettesSmoked()
const alcoholDrunk = this.getAlcoholDrunk()
return (
  <div>
    <button className='arrow-left' onClick={() => this.setState({firstThree: true})} />
    <ul className='list-icons list-inline'>
      {
         firstThree && <li className='calendar-icon'>
        <Medicines medicinesTaken={medicinesTaken} increment={this.incrementMedicines} decrement={this.decrementMedicines} />
         </li>
      }
      {
         firstThree &&
         <li className='calendar-icon'>
        <Meals mealsConsumed={mealsConsumed} increment={this.incrementMeals} decrement={this.decrementMeals} />
      </li>
      }

      {
        firstThree && 
        <li className='calendar-icon'>
        <Activities activitiesMinutes={activitiesMinutes} increment={this.incrementActivities}
          decrement={this.decrementActivities} />
      </li>
      }
      {
        !firstThree &&
        <li className='calendar-icon'>*/}
           <Sleep hoursSlept={hoursSlept} increment= {this.incrementSleep} decrement={this.decrementSleep} />
        </li>
      }
      {
         !firstThree &&
         <li className='calendar-icon'>
           <Cigarettes cigarettesSmoked={cigarettesSmoked} increment={this.incrementCigarettes} decrement={this.decrementCigarettes} />
         </li>
      }
      {
         !firstThree &&
         <li className='calendar-icon'> 
           Alcohol alcoholDrunk={alcoholDrunk} increment={this.incrementAlcohol} decrement={this.decrementAlcohol} />
         </li>
      }
    </ul>
    <button className='arrow-right' onClick={() => this.setState({firstThree: false})}/>
  </div>
)
```

I haven't tested the code, but should put you in the right direction.

Comment: I will check it tomorrow and I will get back to you.

Anyway thanks for your participation Hamza. Appreciated.

Comment: No problem, also edited the answer as you commented out. Can be done that way too. @Rachomir

Comment: What if let say I will have more elements than 6? - 9 or 12. In that case I think this logic won't work. I mean clicking on the previous/next arrow wont show correct array elements. Em I right?

Comment: @Rachomir then you can use the first solution with loop. I'll edit my answer so that it can be generic. So you just needs to add 3 when clicked right and subtract 3 when clicked on left.